in_app_webview write function to website that will detect if i open the website via browser or via flutter
I would expand to make my question more clearly:
i have a flutter app and a website. inside the flutter app i have a webview of the website. i want that in the webview the ui and functionality will be a little different than the actual website. for example, if there is a button in the website that is red, i want it to be blue on the flutter app. is there a way through in_app_webview to send a function to the website's javascript that return a boolean if the website was opened via flutter or not, and change the website's code accordingly. is what im asking to do possible? and how do i do that?
thanks in advance :)

I think it possible by send custom header to web
InAppWebView(
        initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
          url: Uri.parse("https://example.com"),
          headers: {
            "from_flutter": "true",
          },
        ),
 ),

or Do it manually by inject javascript to in_app_webview to change color or whatever you want
https://inappwebview.dev/docs/5.x.x/webview/javascript/injection/

and sorry for the noob follow up question. how do i get this header in the client website?

@YuvalPoliak It depend on you web language like react was use
app.get('/example-path' , (request , response) => header = request.header) something like this
